# Why is Maven downloading from the wrong repository?

Tags: maven

I'm a newbie to Maven. I'm trying to setup a local Archiva 1.3.6 server to act as a repository server for a project's internal artifact, as well as mirror to external repos. Things work fine except for snapshots. I'm using Maven version 3.0.5.

Here are the mirror settings in my `settings.xml` file

```xml
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>internal</id>
        <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
        <name>My Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://my.repo.server:9000/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

During the build, Maven tries to download the snapshot artifact from the wrong repository. I have 2 repositories set in the parent's parent `pom.xml`: `internal` and `snapshots`.

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://my.repo.server:9000/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://my.repo.server:9000/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

In the project's `pom.xml` I have the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>metadata-framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

During the build Maven tries to do this:

```
Downloading: 
.../archiva/repository/**snapshots**/com/mygroup/metadata-framework/1.0.3.SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Downloaded: 
.../archiva/repository/**snapshots**/com/mygroup/metadata-framework/1.0.3.SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (795 B at 16.9 KB/sec)

Downloading: 
.../archiva/repository/**internal**/com/mygroup/metadata-framework/1.0.3.20130908.081541-1/cems-metadata-framework-1.0.3.20130908.081541-1.pom

[WARNING] The POM for com.myground:metadata-framework:jar:1.0.3.20130908.081541-1 is missing, no dependen
cy information available
```

I verified the files in `snapshot` repo is correct, that it has properly generated maven-metadata.xml and etc. it appears that Maven downloaded the metadata correctly from `snapshot` repo, determined the right timestamped version, but somehow it decided to download the actual file from `internal` repo instead of `snapshots`, which lead to 404 and failed build.

I have no idea how Maven works, please help.

Comment: So ... isn't there a typo in the POM resolution ? com.mygrounD <-

Answer (score 0):

@lee - Here's how I download custom artifacts from an internal snapshots repo within Archiva.  I use this config every day.
settingsl.xml:

Let's say I have a virtual repo named "`help`".
`help` is comprised of outside-facing repos and 2 internal-facing repos.  Those 2 internal-facing repos are:
`help-internal`
`help-snapshots`

Under the `<mirrors>` section, I declare:

```xml
<mirror>
    <id>help</id>
    <mirrorOf>*, !help-snapshots</mirrorOf>
    <name>The Help Repository</name>
    <url>http://blah:8080/archiva/repository/help/</url>
</mirror>
```

Under the `<servers>` section, I declare:

```xml
<server>
    <id>help</id>
    <username>my_user_name</username>
    <password>{my_encrypted_pwd}</password>
</server>
<server>
    <id>help-snapshots</id>
    <username>my_user_name</username>
    <password>{my_encrypted_pwd}</password>
</server>
```

And now the final bit.  In my projects' pom's that use in-house snapshots, I include this:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>help-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://blah:8080/archiva/repository/help-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

More concisely, and without modifying any `pom.xml`, you could define an `all` repository group in archiva which contains both `internal` and `snapshots`, and then add the following in your `.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror><id>myGroup</id><mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://my.repo.server:9000/archiva/repository/all/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile><id>alwaysactive</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository><id>unused</id><url>unused</url></repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old by in order for maven to search in a snapshot repository the version should end with "-SNAPSHOT" (rather than ".SNAPSHOT")